# Rotate polygons around edge (animation nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

`Polygon offset` node (AN v2.1) has an advanced option of rotating around custom pivot point.

How can I tell polygons to rotate around an edge instead of poly's center? Does it require recombining mesh data, indices and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Extract Polygon Transforms* node can be used to generate transformation matrices that can be used as the pivot of the *Offset Polygons* node. In which case, the first edge in the polygon is used.

[image: Node Tree]

Note that you should switch to local axis transformation in the advanced node settings of the *Offset* node.

Comment: Wow, so simple! I was mentally preparing for organising loops to iterate each poly...

Comment: @SergeL haha, it seems loops keep you awake at night :D